# Is custom google Plus button allowed by Google?

Tags: social-sharing-buttons

I wanted to know if it's allowed to use custom Google Plus and Twitter social share buttons. I've seen many jQuery plugins using custom designed buttons and I am not sure whether to use them or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple resources from Google regarding branding guidelines as well as tools for creating buttons. In the buttons policy they state

> Publishers may not alter or obfuscate a Google+ button

And

> Publisher must use only the official Google-provided icon or a plain text and link combination

That being said custom buttons are prolific on the web and very hard to police, so you are probably safe to use one, just not  technically compliant to the policy.

[Google Buttons Policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy)
[Google Brand Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines?hl=en)
[Developer custom buttons](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button)
[Twitter brand guidelines](https://about.twitter.com/company/brand)
[Twitter assets](https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets)

Comment: As well, it is more that the copyrighted/trademark G+ logo (for a lack of a better word) is really what is important. It is perfectly reasonable to make a button as long as the logo is recognizable as intended. Google likely will not squawk too loudly (if at all) if this is the case.